# calling ajax on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple html button.

When I click it, the ajax is called.

This is my code.

```
 <INPUT type="button" class="form6form" id="newsubmit" name="newsubmit" value="Submit">
```

And here is the ajax full code.

I want the ajax to validate my code and then use success handler

```
 $('body').on('click', '#newsubmit', function (event) {

    $("#form6").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            plnonew: "required",
            pldtnew: "required",
            noboxnew: "required",
        },
        messages: {

            plnonew: "Please select a pack list id..",
            pldtnew: "Please select a date..",
            noboxnew: "Please select a box no..",
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "try.php",
                data: $('#form6').serialize(),
                cache: false,

                success: function (html) {

                    var div1 = $(html).filter('#div1');

                    loading_hide();
                    $("#container").html(div1);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Nothing happens when i click the button.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: What ajax code? The click handler is empty, what did you expect!

Comment: @adeneo the ajax code is fine. I didn't add up. The click has no effect. thanks

Comment: what are you expecting the ajax to do?

Comment: You are missing a `)` at the end of that code, but that is probably just a typo. Also what is your code within the click event? We can't read minds.

Comment: @ChrisTill validate my form..will add the full ajax code now!! thanks

Comment: @TimBJames i have added up the code..thanks!

Comment: If you place an alert inside the event handler, is it triggered ?

Comment: ya the ajax call is working. i checked that. @adeneo

Comment: `type="button"` should be `type="submit"`. Regular buttons do not fire submit handlers automatically. Submit buttons do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At html code client Side index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function myCall() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "GET",            
            dataType: "html"
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            $("#mybox").html(msg);          
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
</script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>My jQuery Ajax test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #mybox {
                width: 300px;
                height: 250px;
                border: 1px solid #999;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        The following div will be updated after the call:<br />
        <div id="mybox">

        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Update" />

    </body>
</html>
```

At server side ajax.php file

```
<?php
echo '<p>Hi I am some random ' . rand() .' output from the server.</p>';

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `submitHandler` in the validate plugin replaces the native submit, an input with the type `button` will not submit the form and trigger the `sumbitHandler`, so change this:

```
<INPUT type="button" class="form6form" id="newsubmit" name="newsubmit" value="Submit">
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" class="form6form" id="newsubmit" name="newsubmit" value="Submit">
```

And initialize the validation outside the click handler.